# Let $a,b,c\in R$. If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is such that $a+b+c=3$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$ for all $x,y\in R$...

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $a,b,c\in R$. If $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ is such that $a+b+c=3$ and $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$ for all $x,y\in R$. Then $\sum_{n=1}^{10} f(n)$ is

From the first equation

$$a(x^2+y^2+2xy)+b(x+y)+c=ax^2+bx+c+ay^2+by+c+xy$$

$$2axy=c+xy$$

Also, the summation will be

$$a(1^2+2^2+3^2...10^2)+b(1+2+3+4...+10)+10c$$
$$=385a+55b+10c$$
$$375a+45b+30$$ 
I don’t know what to do with the x and y terms. How do  I proceed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have that

$$f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

for *all* $x,y\in R$. Your simplification of \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$2axy=c+xy \implies (2a-1)xy = c \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

Since this is true for *every* real $x$ and $y$, this means that $2a - 1 = 0 \implies a = \frac{1}{2}$ and $c = 0$. This thus gives that $b = 3 - a - c = \frac{5}{2}$. Can you finish the rest?

Comment: So what you did was use $x=y=1$ and assumed $c$ to be zero?

Comment: @Aditya If $2a - 1 = 0$, then $c = 0$. Otherwise, you can divide both sides by $2a - 1$ to get $xy = \frac{c}{2a - 1}$. The right side is a constant, but you can vary the left side of $xy$ to get any real value, which is not possible.

Comment: So either $x$ or $y$ or both are zero by ‘compulsion ’?

Comment: @Aditya No, there's no "compulsion" for $x$ and/or $y$ to be any particular values, including $0$. Instead, as stated in the question, the relation in ($1$) must hold for *all* real $x$ and $y$. The only way for that to be true, based on the simplification of the equivalent relation in ($2$) is if $2a - 1 = 0$ and $c = 0$. In that case, and *only* in that case, $xy$ can be any real value, including the result any possible real value of $x$ and for $y$.

Answer (score 3):

From $a+b+c=3$, we have $$f(1)=a+b+c=3$$
and from $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)+xy$, we have
$$f(x+1)=f(x)+f(1)+x=f(x)+x+3$$
therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(n+1)=\sum_{n=1}^{10} (f(n)+n+3)$$
or $$\sum_{n=2}^{11}f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^{10}f(n)+\sum_{n=1}^{10}(n+3)$$
can you proceed?

Comment: In last line, why did $n+1$ change to $n$? I also noticed you changed it to $n=2$ below the sigma

Comment: Starting from $n=1$ for summing $f(n+1)$ gives: $f(2)+f(3)+\cdots$. Starting from $n=2$ for summing $f(n)$ gives: $f(2)+f(3)+\cdots$, so we change the index to match summands.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

$a+b+c=3 \equiv f(1)=3$. Using recurrence relation, $f(2)=2f(1)+1=7$, $f(3)=12$, $f(4)=18$. Notice the pattern.

$$\begin{aligned}a+b+c&=3\\4a+2b+c&=7\\9a+3b+c&=12\end{aligned}$$

This gives $a=1/2$, $b=5/2$, $c=0$. Can you proceed?

Answer (score 1):

From your third step you get $c=0$ and $a=1/2, \implies 1/2+b+0=3 \implies b=5/2$.
Next, $f(n)=n^2/2+5n/2$, then
$$S_m=\sum_{n=1}^{m} (n^2/2+5n/2)= \frac{m(m+1)(2m+1)}{12}+\frac{5m(m+1)}{4}$$
$$\implies S_m=\frac{m(m+1)(m+8)}{6}$$
then $$S_{10}=10.11.18/6=330$$